# Script won't for more than one group when looking at results of whoami command

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, shell-script

Trying to setup IF/ELSE on a script whereby it checks for two conditions to be met before the script runs:

1. Check if the following file exists on the desktop. (`$FileExists`)
2. Check if the user is a member of only one group containing 6 digits it's group name. (`$GroupCount`)

Continue if the results of `whoami /groups` yields only one result where group name contains _6digits

```
E.G
Mygroup_152452_152354
```

Do not continue if the results of `whoami /groups` shows more than one result where group name contains _6digits

```
E.G
Mygroup1_152452_152354
Mygroup2_152453_152355
```

I've used -le 1 but I don't think I'm going about it the correct way? A bit stumped and would greatly appreciate if someone could help me see where it's gone wrong?

Currently, the script jumps to exit when I run it from a user that should satisfy the equal to 1 or less condition (only a member of one group containing _6digits).

```
$WantFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\myfile.lnk"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
$Groups = WhoAmI /Groups /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
$GroupCount = $Groups.'Group Name'.Where{ $Groups -match '(_\d{6}){1}'} -le 1


If ($FileExists -eq $False -And $GroupCount -eq $True)

{

Write-Host "Carry on script"

}

Else {

Write-Host "Exit the script"
Exit

}
```

Comment: Try either `-le 2`  or `-eq 1` when checking $GroupCount

Comment: Thanks Reddy. Will try that now. Was just wondering if there was a way to do this using measure-object

Comment: -le 2 and -eq 1 didn't work sadly

Comment: what is the value of $GroupCount just before the IF statement?

Comment: It doesn't return a value such as 1 but rather it returns a single result such as MyGroup_123456_123456

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add .Count. What is the value of `$GroupCount.Count` just before the if statement? Is it what you are expecting?

Comment: Of course! forgot about adding .count at the end! adding -eq 1 to this now works a charm. Thanks Reddy!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Reddy Lutonadio for the guidance on this.

After testing this is what worked for me:

```
$WantFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\myfile.lnk"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
$Groups = WhoAmI /Groups /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
$GroupResults = $Groups.'Group Name'.Where{ $_ -match '(_\d{6}){1}'}


If ($FileExists -eq $False -And $GroupResults.count -eq 1)

{

Write-Host "Carry on script"

}

Else {

Write-Host "Exit the script"
Exit

}
```

Adding `.count` to the end of `$GroupResults` within the `If` statement allowed me to use `eq 1`